# What are some ways to make a <li></li> element vanish with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, html-lists

I am trying to make a <li> </li> disappear.

Using .css('display', 'none') or .hide() has not worked. Here is my code:

```
                } else {
                        $("#enter_number").css('display', 'none');
                        $("#validate_menu").css('display', 'none');
                        $("#phone_verified").fadeIn();
                }
```

Here is HTML:

```
    <ul>
    <li><a href='account.php'>Account Home</a></li>
    <li><a href='user_settings.php'>User Settings</a></li>
    <li name='validate_menu'><a href=verify_mobile.php>Validate Mobile</a></li>
    <li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Do you have any `<li>`'s with `id='enter_number'` or `id='validate_menu'`?  That's what the CSS selectors are looking for.  I see a `<li>` with the name `validate_menu` but none with that as the id.

Comment: In your javascript code, you are referencing id's, while your `<li>` tags don't have any id's. Give them an id then you can simply say `$("#myId").hide();`

Comment: The #enter_number and #phone_verified work just fine. It is making the #validate_menu vanish that I am having a problem with.

Comment: Was there a `<li id='enter_number'>`?  If so that would explain why that one worked.

Comment: You typed `name='validate_menu'` instead of `id='validate_menu'`. Btw, names are used in form elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/750krser/4/ Here is a jsFiddle (with id="") demonstrating it not working? Did I Fiddle that correct?

Comment: The `<button>` in your fiddle has a `name`, not an `id`. Scroll down to my answer and check my fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a name instead of an id.

```
<ul>
<li><a href='account.php'>Account Home</a></li>
<li><a href='user_settings.php'>User Settings</a></li>
<li id='validate_menu'><a href='verify_mobile.php'>Validate Mobile</a></li>
<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
</ul>
```

Should work.

Here's an example as I saw in your comments that you are still having issues.

http://jsfiddle.net/9rzn57s1/